# Get the Text of AutoCAD AcDbText object with python

Tags: python-3.x, com, autocad

### What is the best way, in python, to get the text of an AcDbText object?

I am working in python, win32com, and autoCAD.  I would like to be able to do the following, via a python program:

- Place objects into a selection set
- Determine which are AcDbText objects
- From those, extract the text and then delete.

I can do the first two things just fine. However, assuming `textObj` is the correct type of object, the following achieves half the remaining-- `t` will contain the text desired as a str:

```
t = textObj.copy().fieldcode()
```

- Problem 1:  As the code implies, this creates a copy of the object, right there in the drawing, and does not seem to provide a way to identify it later for deletion.
- Problem 2:  The original object resists deletion from the selection set.  If `selection` is the selection set, then no variation of `selection.clear()`, `selection.delete()`, or `selection.erase()` does anything.  (I have checked the length of selection set before and after the fieldcode() invocation-- the number of objects remains the same.)

I am puzzled that there does not seem to be a way to prize the text out of the object without copying it.  What am I missing?

Per question in comments to an answer, the output of `pprint(dir(textObj))` is:

```
['AddRef', 
'Application', 
'ArrayPolar', 
'ArrayRectangular', 
'Copy', 
'Database', 
'Delete', 
'Document',  
'EntityName', 
'EntityTransparency', 
'EntityType', 
'Erase',  
'GetBoundingBox', 
'GetExtensionDictionary',  
'GetIDsOfNames', 
'GetTypeInfo', 
'GetTypeInfoCount', 
'GetXData', 
'Handle', 
'HasExtensionDictionary', 
'Highlight', 
'Hyperlinks', 
'IntersectWith', 
'Invoke', 
'Layer', 
'Linetype', 
'LinetypeScale', 
'Lineweight', 
'Material', 
'Mirror', 
'Mirror3D', 
'Move', 
'ObjectID', 
'ObjectName', 
'OwnerID', 
'PlotStyleName', 
'QueryInterface', 
'Release', 
'Rotate', 
'Rotate3D', 
'ScaleEntity', 
'SetXData', 
'TransformBy', 
'TrueColor', 
'Update', 
'Visible', 
'_AddRef', 
'_GetIDsOfNames', 
'_GetTypeInfo', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_ArrayPolar', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_ArrayRectangular', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Copy', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_GetBoundingBox', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Highlight', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_IntersectWith', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Mirror', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Mirror3D', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Move', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Rotate', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Rotate3D', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_ScaleEntity', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_TransformBy', 
'_IAcadEntity__com_Update', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_EntityName', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_EntityTransparency', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_EntityType', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_Hyperlinks', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_Layer', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_Linetype', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_LinetypeScale', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_Lineweight', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_Material', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_PlotStyleName', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_TrueColor', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_Visible', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__get_color', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_EntityTransparency', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_Layer', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_Linetype', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_LinetypeScale', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_Lineweight', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_Material', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_PlotStyleName', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_TrueColor', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_Visible', 
'_IAcadEntity__com__set_color', 
'_IAcadObject__com_Delete', 
'_IAcadObject__com_Erase', 
'_IAcadObject__com_GetExtensionDictionary', 
'_IAcadObject__com_GetXData', 
'_IAcadObject__com_SetXData', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_Application', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_Database', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_Document', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_Handle', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_HasExtensionDictionary', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_ObjectID', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_ObjectName', 
'_IAcadObject__com__get_OwnerID', 
'_IDispatch__com_GetIDsOfNames', 
'_IDispatch__com_GetTypeInfo', 
'_IDispatch__com_GetTypeInfoCount', 
'_IDispatch__com_Invoke', 
'_IUnknown__com_AddRef', 
'_IUnknown__com_QueryInterface', 
'_IUnknown__com_Release', 
'_Invoke', 
'_QueryInterface', 
'_Release', 
'__bool__', 
'__class__', 
'__cmp__', 
'__com_interface__', 
'__ctypes_from_outparam__', 
'__del__', 
'__delattr__', 
'__dict__', 
'__dir__', 
'__doc__', 
'__eq__', 
'__format__', 
'__ge__', 
'__getattr__', 
'__getattribute__', 
'__gt__', 
'__hash__', 
'__init__', 
'__init_subclass__', 
'__le__', 
'__lt__', 
'__map_case__', 
'__module__', 
'__ne__', 
'__new__', 
'__reduce__', 
'__reduce_ex__', 
'__repr__', 
'__setattr__', 
'__setstate__', 
'__sizeof__', 
'__str__', 
'__subclasshook__', 
'__weakref__', 
'_b_base_', 
'_b_needsfree_', 
'_case_insensitive_', 
'_compointer_base__get_value', 
'_idlflags_', 
'_iid_', 
'_invoke', 
'_methods_', 
'_needs_com_addref_', 
'_objects', 
'_type_', 
'color', 
'from_param', 
'value']
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `textObj` is either a single-line text object (`AcDbText`) or multiline text object (`AcDbMText`), then you should be able to obtain the text content using the [`TextString`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-E54B1951-5BF5-4524-97E6-DFB4E4A20109) property, e.g.:

```
t = textObj.TextString
```

---

Note that the methods [`clear()`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-C9A0A555-B8B8-4CB3-86D4-EE8B7D5ED532) & [`delete()`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-167FBA5F-C3F3-4195-A170-02E5E46EC797) when invoked on an ActiveX [SelectionSet object](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-BF264239-CF7D-4BC8-8D37-69477862DB5A) do not delete the objects it contains, but rather remove the objects from the SelectionSet and delete the SelectionSet object respectively. Though, the [`erase()`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-54A5C5A5-5156-4470-A057-12C222CE3DAE) method should successfully erase all objects contained in the SelectionSet.

Though, to delete an object, you would typically just invoke the `delete()` method on the object itself, e.g.:

```
textObj.Delete()
```

Comment: `textObj.entityname` yields `AcDbText`, but `textObj` has no `TextString` attribute.  Doesn't show up on `print(dir(textObj))`, and throws an error when trying this solution.

Comment: Far too many to put in a comment-- I put them in the main post.  None of them look relevant.